# How to issue tokens with typ: jwt instead of at+jwt in Identity Server 4?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Identity Server 4 in contrary to Identity Server 3 issues tokens with default value `"typ": "at+jwt"`, however I still need to issue older version of token, meaning `"typ": "jwt"`.

Is there any way to overwrite default configuration of IS4 and issue JWT token of `"typ": "jwt"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `AccessTokenJwtType` on `AddIdentityServer`:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
                options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                options.AccessTokenJwtType = "JWT";
            })
```

Here I explained it in [my blog post](https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-web-api/#jwtheadertype) as well

Comment: Is this `EmitStaticAudienceClaim` is always necessary? I've read you're post and I understood: if it doesn't work ad EmitStaticAudienceClaim. But I don't know when this is valid.

Comment: It is not always required, its needed when we use IDS4 + .NET Framework MVC app or API (none .NET Core or .NET 5). This will emit an `aud` claim in the `issuer_name/resources` format. @Yoda

Comment: A topic from a few years ago, but is there a way to choose the type per client?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just have to set this IdentityServer option to jwt:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value for the JWT typ header for access tokens.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The JWT typ value.
    /// </value>
    public string AccessTokenJwtType { get; set; } = "at+jwt";
```

See the source code for it [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/DependencyInjection/Options/IdentityServerOptions.cs):